# Windows Network - Can't refer to \\Server

Tags: windows

We're setting up a small network, 2 or 3 computers. We designated one computer as Server1. Computer2 can access Server1 like so: \\Server1\Folder1

However because of an application configuration issue, on Server1, it needs to reference itself in the same way. But on Server1, windows doesn't recognize \\Server1\Folder1 for some reason.

I'm having trouble getting that working.

Comment: Please tell us what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks! From Computer2, I can enter \\Server1\Folder1 in the Windows Explorer and it works. But from Server1 itself, when I enter that into the Windows folder I get: Windows can not access \\Server1 ...

Comment: If you try to access to the folder by IP does it works?
What happen if you try to ping your server from itself?
It looks like he can't resolve his hostname.

Comment: Please post the output of `ipconfig /all` and `nslookup server1`, both run from Server1.

Comment: Thankyou both. By IP Address, now why didn't I think of that. It should work, I hope. I will try to run ipconfig /all and nslookup server1 and post the result. This place is remote to me, so next time I can arrange to connect...

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but can you Ping Server1 from Server1 just to make sure DNS is working fine. 
Also, check the Share and NTFS Permissions...can you get to \Server1\C$ ? If you can then it's a Share permission issue if not then you'll need to check Share and NTFS permissions.
Let me know how you get on and if I can help further.